# How to add extra fields to form depending on category chosen?

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database

I have a news site with categories:

- Courses
- Jobs
- News
- Help Request

The categories are used to define 'Posts'

Anybody can submit a post with any category chosen, using a common submit form. However, 'Courses' and 'Jobs' must have a 'start' and 'end' date, whereas 'News' and 'Help Request' don't need these fields.

What would be the best practice in getting this data using the same submission form?

Would it be best to check for the category of the new post, and then request the start/end date, and any other data specific to that category in a new form?

Or allow the data to go through as nulls where it is not required? How would you check what category the user is submitting into?

Comment: I guess I would have the user select the category from a drop down menu and then use jQuery to check that value and show specific text fields based off that selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide all the forms and use the hide option to hide the forms who are not relevant at that time. When you select the category with a control, you can use some JavaScript to hide the irrelevant controls and make the others visible.

In any case the script who handles the content should be intelligent enough to only process relevant data. So if the users enters some irrelevant data, it should be discarded.

Comment: Great, is this common practice? It seems common sense now, but I haven't ever done it

Comment: Additionally, would you add these extra fields (start/end date) to a 'Courses' table, or include it within the more generic posts table?

Comment: @gray Yes, it's quite common. You shouldn't put irrelevant fields in database tables.

Comment: If I recall correctly the definition of Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF), I would generate let's say the following tables: `Post`, `Category1`, `Category2`. If your post is in category 1, the identifier in that table should link to that post. This is useful since you reduce the amount of duplicated (and NULL) data

Comment: How about if there is already a categories table which also includes the category name (or course name).. if I was then to add a 'courses' table, it also would need a course name, which would be duplication? What would you do in this situation?

Comment: No, you maintain a `post` table who stores everything that is common to a post (for instance its `content`, `author`,...). Then you generate a table for each kind of post who stores what is specific for that kind of post (`start`- and `stop`-dates,...). If there are two categories who have `start`-`stop` dates in common you can generate a single table.